# Remove object from Active Record Relation without deleting it

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, relational-database

I'm working in Ruby on Rails 4 with Postgresql, and I've hit a bit of a snag. We have an Active Record model called `AttendanceRecord` which belongs to an `AttendanceDay`, `AttendanceSwipe`, `Course`, and `CourseTimeSlot`. Attendance Records were supposed to be unique on these fields, but something went wrong and duplicates snuck in. So, I wrote a method to find all of the Attendance Records which were duplicated and only keep one of them.

In the course of that method, I built an Active Record Relation of objects that shared the same attributes, like so:

`records = AttendanceRecord.where(course_id: attributes[0], course_time_slot_id: attributes[1], attendance_swipe_id: attributes[2], attendance_day_id: attributes[3])`

Nice relation, right?

Next, I found the object that I wanted to keep and named it `to_keep`. Then, I tried to remove just that object from the relation, like this:

`records.delete(to_keep)`

Unfortunately, I discovered that the `delete` method works a little differently on a Relation than it does on an Array. Instead of simply removing the object from the list, it actually does delete it from the database (without the callbacks).

So: I'm wondering if there is a method that I'm missing that will remove my `to_keep` object from the Relation without actually touching the object itself. Then, I'll be able to safely call `records.destroy_all` and happily go about my business. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to exclude an object from a relation you can do so by id. For example:

```
records.where('id <> ?', to_keep.id).destroy_all
```

or, thanks to @trushkevich, in rails 4 you can do:

```
records.where.not(id: to_keep.id).destroy_all
```

This means that `destroy_all` will be called on the records you've identified already but excluding the `to_keep` record.

Comment: in rails 4 you can do `records.where.not(id: to_keep.id).destroy_all`

Comment: Good point. I've edited the answer to include that option too. Thanks.